# Apache2 not pointing to the WordPress directory

Tags: wordpress, apache2, lamp

First I followed this tutorial:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-wordpress-alongside-lamp-on-debian-10/

Which worked fine until I got to the step where I needed to set the permissions.  After that, when I try to `cd wordpress` I get Permission Denied, so I had to `sudo su` to continue following the directions.

Then in step 6 where you set the DocumentRoot, I followed that to the latter.

Now on step 7, where you actually test if you can access the WordPress initial installation screens, Apache2 is still displaying the Default apache2 static page.

I found this tutorial as well:
https://dade2.net/how-to-install-lamp-wordpress-ubuntu-and-debian/

While that second one is more recent, the only difference is that it uses slightly different Permissions and uses MariaDB.  So I tried their Permissions and can now cd into wordpress without sudo su.

But the apache2 static page is still there.

Has something changed with Apache2 or WordPress that's preventing it from pointing to WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are trying to install apache2 with WordPress. I would suggest you to follow these steps and let me know, if it helps.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

## Install apache

```
$ sudo apt install apache2
```

3. Verify your Apache installation by typing "http://your-ip-address" in your favourite browser.

`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'`  # can help you to get your IP address.

4. If you have firewall installed run this command to enable port 80. If you don't have firewall, skip this step.

`$ sudo ufw allow 'Apache`'

Install wordpress

```
1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install wordpress php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php-mysql
3. cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
4. sudo vi wordpress.conf
```

#Add these lines in wordpress.conf

```
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

5. sudo a2ensite wordpress 
6. sudo a2enmod rewrite 
7. sudo service apache2 reload
```

Now Configure mysql

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
```

## Once you get mysql prompt, Run create, grant, Flush and quit command as follows -

```
$ mysql> CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
```

## set username and password

```
$ mysql> create user 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test1234';
```

Run these commands

```
 mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER ON wordpress.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost';
    
    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    
    mysql> quit
```

Now, configure "/etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php file to link MySQL DB "WordPress" created above. create the config-localhost.php, if doesn't exist.

## add these lines

```
<?php
    define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
    define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test1234');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
    define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content');
    ?>
```

Restart mysql service

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Login to your WordPress by opening "localhost/blog/wp-login.php".
I found this [link](https://cloudlinuxtech.com/install-apache-in-ubuntu/), may be helpful for you. It shows each step screenshot also.

Comment: This worked magically.  But when I went to http://myipaddress/blog I got an error that neither /etc/wordpress/config-[ipaddress].php was found.  so I copied config-localhost.php and named it to the file it wanted.  Now can access.  How do I get Apache2 to point to that as the document root though and just need the config-localhost?

Comment: Not sure but I can see one section in the link I provided for further help, "How to host a website in Apache server on Ubuntu".  Just have a look if that's the issue you are facing, may be it can help you. Because i never faced any issue following these steps.